# Bash command line arguments passed to sed via ssh

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh, sed

I am looking to write a simple script to perform a SSH command on many hosts simultaneously, and which hosts exactly are generated from another script.  The problem is that when I run the script using sometihng like sed it doesn't work properly.

It should run like `sshall.sh {anything here}` and it will run the `{anything here}` part on all the nodes in the list.

`sshall.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

NODES=`listNodes | grep "node-[0-9*]" -o`

echo "Connecting to all nodes and running: ${@:1}"

for i in $NODES
do
   :
        echo "$i : Begin"
        echo "----------------------------------------"

        ssh -q -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no"  $i "${@:1}"

        echo "----------------------------------------"
        echo "$i : Complete";
        echo ""
done
```

When it is run with something like `whoami` it works but when I run:

```
[root@myhost bin]# sshall.sh sed -i '/^somebeginning/ s/$/,appendme/' /etc/myconfig.conf
Connecting to all nodes and running: sed -i /^somebeginning/ s/$/,appendme/ /etc/myconfig.conf

node-1 : Begin
----------------------------------------
sed: -e expression #1, char 18: missing command
----------------------------------------
node-1 : Complete

node-2 : Begin
----------------------------------------
sed: -e expression #1, char 18: missing command
----------------------------------------
node-2 : Complete

…
```

Notice that the quotes disappear on the sed command when sent to the remote client.

1. How do I go about fixing my bash command?
2. Is there a better way of achieving this?

Comment: You probably want to say `sshall.sh $(sed -i '/^somebeginning/ s/$/,appendme/' /etc/myconfig.conf)`. That is, feed `sshall.sh` with the output of the command `sed ...`.

Comment: I don't think so, I actually want to run that `sed` command on every node (nodes 1-n), not the node that i am running the command from; unless that will actually run it on each node?

Comment: Uhms, I see. However, this is weird: you pass a full sed command as a set of arguments to a script. It looks very fragile. Also, what is `listNodes`?

Comment: `listNodes` is the command that gives me a list of all the nodes that I need to connect to (with some other info I grep out).  All nodes are identical so it isn't too bad to work with

Comment: You just need to escape the `$`. Try `sshall.sh sed -i '/^somebeginning/ s/\\\$/,appendme/' /etc/myconfig.conf`.

Comment: By the time you are getting around to escaping the spaces so that you can run the command on the remote machine, it is getting far too complex and it would almost certainly be better to create a script file, copy that to the target host, and run that than to spend the time working out how many times your command line is evaluated so that you can get the right amount of escaping in place.  If that's too radical, ensure you don't need spaces: `sshall.sh sed -i '/^somebeginning/s/$/,appendme/' /etc/myconfig.conf`.  If you need to deal with spaces, it gets really hard.

Comment: @alvits Thanks, but no cigar, still returns `sed: -e expression #1, char 18: missing command` with either two or three escapes

Comment: @JonathanLeffler you are probably right there is likely a faster way of doing it, but I will need to use this script for many different tasks, and at this point I am really curious how this problem would be solved. There has to be a way to pass along a command from one to another.

Comment: There (probably) are ways to do it; they aren't easy — and in my experience, they aren't foolproof, because some damn fool (usually me) finds a new way to break things.  OTOH, copying a script and executing it — that can be made close to fool-proof without an excess of effort. (Note that `whoami` (and `who am i`) work because you don't have to worry about preserving spaces in arguments and aren't dealing with metacharacters.)

Comment: BTW, `for i in $NODES` has some gotchas to it; see [DontReadLinesWithFor](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor). (Not that there aren't gotchas to the while loop with `ssh` in it -- you'll want to be sure that ssh doesn't eat stdin contents intended to be read by the loop; however, if you're feeding it stdin from a heredoc, as suggested in my answer, that's moot).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, ...since the answer I've provided is a pattern I tend to reuse, I'd appreciate some efforts at finding a way to break it. :)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: If the remote host doesn't have Bash, you've (still) got problems. I'm not sure if this counts, but if `dash` uses a [`printf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html) command that's strictly POSIX compliant, using `%q` with `dash` leads to unspecified behaviour.  That is, POSIX does not specify what `%q` does. The `-v cmd_q` is also a Bash extension (or, at least, not part of POSIX).  I think those don't count against your code. I'm not sufficiently au fait with modern Korn shell or Zsh to know what they do; I'm barely into the early 90s at times.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: where you've got Bash around, it looks like you should be OK.  I think I'd probably work in terms of a file containing the command to be executed remotely — your suggestion of using `bash -s` and redirection of the script seems solid (and probably works for multiple shells — `sh -s` for example).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, ...the problem with `sh -s` is that it doesn't guarantee that `printf '%q'` content will parse back to original form -- think of the case where it generated a string of the form `$'foo\nbar'`. This is why I'm very explicitly relying on bash on both ends. Since we're in a bash-tagged question, I don't think I'm too far out-of-line by doing so.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Substitute an `eval`-safe quoted version of your command into a heredoc:

```
#!/bin/bash
#      ^^^^- not /bin/sh; printf %q is an extension

# Put your command into a single string, with each argument quoted to be eval-safe
printf -v cmd_q '%q ' "$@"

while IFS= read -r hostname; do
  # run bash -s remotely, with that string passed on stdin
  ssh -q -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' "$hostname" "bash -s" <<EOF
$cmd_q
EOF
done < <(listNodes | grep -o -e "node-[0-9*]")
```

---

Why this works reliably (and other approaches don't):

- `printf %q` knows how to quote contents to be eval'd by that same shell (so spaces, wildcards, various local quoting methods, etc. will always be supported).
- Arguments given to `ssh` **are not passed to the remote command individually!**
  Instead, they're concatenated into a string passed to `sh -c`.
- However: The output of `printf %q` is not portable to all POSIX-derived shells! It's guaranteed to be compatible with *the same shell locally in use* -- ksh will always parse output from `printf '%q'` in ksh, bash will parse output from `printf '%q'` in bash, etc; thus, you can't safely pass this string on the remote argument vector, because it's `/bin/sh` -- not `bash` -- running there. (If you know your remote `/bin/sh` is provided by bash, *then* you can run `ssh "$hostname" "$cmd_q"` safely, but only under this condition).
- `bash -s` reads the script to run from stdin, meaning that passing your command there -- not on the argument vector -- ensures that it'll be parsed into arguments *by the same shell that escaped it to be shell-safe*.

Comment: Wow, that was a really really helpful answer! Very good information about how things are working behind the scenes.

Comment: `bash -s` disallows to read data from stdin by the script.  `producer | script args | consumer` shall look like `producer | sshwrap [sshopts] remote -- script args | consumer`.  Remote is assumed to have `/bin/bash`, but `/bin/sh` is some non-bash-escape-groking shell.  `args` may contain everything evil, like spaces or trailing linefeeds.  `script` must not be changed, of course.  Bonus points, if `sshwrap -t` is supported for scripts, which require stderr to be a TTY while stdin/out stay transparent pipes.  Of course `\n~.` and TTY control sequences must reach the script.  Life is deadly! ;)

Answer (score 3):

You want to pass the entire command -- with all of its arguments, spaces, and quotation marks -- to ssh so it can pass it unchanged to the remote shell for parsing.

One way to do that is to put it all inside single quotation marks. But then you'll also need to make sure the single quotation marks within your command are preserved in the arguments, so the remote shell builds the correct arguments for sed.

```
sshall.sh 'sed -i '"'"'/^somebeginning/ s/$/,appendme/'"'"' /etc/myconfig.conf'
```

It looks redundant, but `'"'"'` is a common Bourne trick to get a single quotation mark into a single-quoted string. The first quote ends single-quoting temporarily, the double-quote-single-quote-double-quote construct appends a single quotation mark, and then the single quotation mark resumes your single-quoted section. So to speak.

Another trick that can be helpful for troubleshooting is to add the `-v` flag do your `ssh` flags, which will spit out lots of text, but most importantly it will show you exactly what string it's passing to the remote shell for parsing and execution.

--

All of this is fairly fragile around spaces in your arguments, which you'll need to avoid, since you're relying on shell parsing on the opposite end.

Comment: You can also, and I normally do, use `'\''`, though the backslash could lead to problems with multiple levels of interpretation, but then you can run into those issues with your intriguing (because I'd not noticed it before) `'"'"'` notation.

Comment: Yep, that's arguably more readable, and it's basically the same thing: telling the local shell to include the single quote in the string.

Comment: As long as you're actually using `bash`, `$'sed -i \'/^somebeginning/ s/$/,appendme/\' /etc/myconfig.conf'` is much easier to read than the quote explosion required by POSIX shell.

Answer (score 1):

Thinking outside the box: instead of dealing with all the quoting issues and the word-splitting in the wrong places, you could attempt to a) construct the script locally (maybe use a here-document?), b) `scp` the script to the remote end, then c) invoke it there. This easily allows more complex command sequences, with all the power of shell control constructs etc. Debugging (checking proper quoting) would be a breeze by simply looking at the generated script.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend reading the command(s) from the standard input rather than from the command line arguments:

*cmd.sh*

```
#!/bin/bash -
# Load server_list with user@host "words" here.

cmd=$(</dev/stdin)

for h in ${server_list[*]}; do
    ssh "$h" "$cmd"
done
```

Usage:

```
./cmd.sh <<'CMD'
sed -i '/^somebeginning/ s/$/,appendme/' /path/to/file1
# other commands
# here...
CMD
```

Alternatively, run `./cmd.sh`, type the command(s), then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd>.

I find the latter variant the most convenient, as you don't even need for here documents, no need for extra escaping. Just invoke your script, type the commands, and press the shortcut. What could be easier?

**Explanations**

The problem with your approach is that the quotes are stripped from the arguments by the shell. For example, the argument `'/^somebeginning/ s/$/,appendme/'` will be interpreted as `/^somebeginning/ s/$/,appendme/` string (without the single quotes), which is an invalid argument for *sed*.

Of course, you can escape the command with the built-in `printf` as suggested in other answer here. But the command becomes not very readable after escaping. For example

```
printf %q 'sed -i /^somebeginning/ s/$/,appendme/ /home/ruslan/tmp/file1.txt'
```

produces

```
sed\ -i\ /\^somebeginning/\ s/\$/\,appendme/\ /home/ruslan/tmp/file1.txt
```

which is not very readable, and will look ugly, if you print it to the screen in order to show the progress.

That's why I prefer to read from the standard input and leave the command intact. My script prints the command strings to the screen, and I see them just in the form I have written them.

---

Note, the `for .. in` loop iterates `$IFS`-separated "words", and is generally not preferred way to traverse an array. It is generally better to invoke `read -r` in a `while` loop with adjusted `$IFS`. I have used the `for` loop for simplicity, as the question is really about invoking the `ssh` command.

Answer (score 0):

Logging into multiple systems over SSH and using the same (or variations on the same) command is the basic use case behind ansible.  The system is not without significant flaws, but for simple use cases is pretty great.  If you want a more solid solution without too much faffing about with escaping and looping over hosts, take a look.

Ansible has a 'raw' module which doesn't even require any dependencies on the target hosts, and you might find that a very simple way to achieve this sort of functionality in a way that frees you from the considerations of looping over hosts, handling errors, marshalling the commands, etc and lets you focus on what you're actually trying to achieve.